# Installer behaves differently on different platforms - Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created an installer for an application, using Visual Studio Installer Projects Version 1.0.0.1 and Visual Studio Version 14.0.25424.00 Update 3, that i intend to run on both Windows 2012 and Windows 2008 platforms. When I build this software from a Windows 7 Desktop, I can install it on both Windows 2012 and Windows 2008 platforms. However, when I build the installer from a Windows 2012 R2 build machine, it installs fine on Windows 2012 platform but fails on Windows 2008 platforms.

Specifically, I get the following error in Event Viewer:

Product: 'My app name' -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: _2B372DBC_02AA_43E3_8851_B2B13B15C27F, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIB80E.tmp, command: /c 'My .cmd filepath'

'My .cmd file' is used as an argument for a cmd.exe Custom Action during commit phase of Installation.

Can I know what is causing this issue? I could not find similar issues occurring in any other forums. I tried checking msi installer logs and didn't find more details about this failure or any differences before failure in successful and failed installation scenarios.

Thanks,
Sai.

Answer (score 0):

What's causing the issue is a custom action. From that log it looks like it's one of your custom actions, not one of the ones that VS setups add internally.

Error 1721 is "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: [2], location: [3], command: [4]"

Without seeing your code and knowing what it's doing it's not possible to add any further information.

Comment: When I was developing this script, I had a few errors in it. If the script has errors, the error that is logged is: Error 1722: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action [2], location: [3], command: [4]. Also, if something is wrong with the script, the cmd.exe program opens. In this case, the cmd.exe does not open. I fixed the issue by building it of a 2008 R2 server. This version works on both 2008 R2 and 2012 R2 platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by building the installer on Windows 2008 R2 system. After building from this platform, the installer runs successfully on both 2012 R2 and 2008 R2 systems.